# IBM Domino database configuration with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, lotus-domino

I am trying to configure IBM domino database with spring boot to fetch the document from IBM domino server.I have added domino NCSO jar in local maven repo and I have wrote the sample Java program for domino connection. Now I want to convert it into spring boot code to connect with domino db and use the database connection in other services to get the data from views. Appreciated for any hits/instruction for the same.

## JAVA Sample :

```
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.Session;

public class JavaAgent {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String host = "test.xxx.xxx.com:63148";
        Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(host);
        String p = s.getCommonUserName();
        System.out.println(p);
        Database db = s.getDatabase("test.xxx.xxx.com", "s.nsf");

        System.out.println(db.getFilePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: did you get it working? Here are a couple of links you might have visited already:
https://github.com/lhervier/dom-spring#ibm-domino-901-plugins-to-develop-web-applications-using-spring-framework
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2594

Answer (score 2):

I am able to connect in spring boot by adding below code in spring boot configuration class:

```
   @Bean
    public DbDirectory dominoConnection() throws NotesException {
        Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, username, password);
        String p = session.getCommonUserName();
        DbDirectory dir = session.getDbDirectory(null);
        String server = dir.getName();
        return dir;
    }

    @Bean
    public Session dominoDBSession() throws NotesException {
        Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, username, password);
        return session;
    }
```